# Exact Time Measuring for Cognitive Experiments

Tags: java, matlab, nanotime, psychtoolbox, time-measurement

we have a java program being used for some cognitive diagnosis in which we have to measure time the most exact way possible. till now it has used psychtoolbox to perform these measurements, but since moving from XP to win7 there is a significant error with these measurements.

it has come to the need of re-programming the time measurement, so we started re-thinking about the whole matlab idea: should we stick with psychtoolbox? maybe java's Nanotime would provide better solution?

Comment: I'd say nanotime would be the most precise solution although it still depends on the implementation of the JVM and the platform. But I'd guess it should provide enough resolution for your needs - although I have no idea what exactly your needs are ;)

Comment: psychtoolbox timing isn't very reliable on windows in general (also for stimulus presentation). You can get more precise timing running it on a linux distribution, eg. Ubuntu